# Howto set focus in Rich Faces panelBarItem?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

Hi
 I want to set focus on `<h:inputText>` element whenever   rich:panelBarItem is opened.
I have:

```
<rich:panelBar>
   <rich:panelBarItem onenter="setFocus();">
      <h:inputText value="#{bean.value}"/>
   </rich:panelBarItem>   
</rich:panelBar>
```

it works fine when I open it with mouse click, but does not work first time when first panelBarItem is automatically opened.
How should I set focus on first opened panelBarItem? I really would like it to be some event(I could not find) on rich:panerBarItem or rich:panelBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your method after page load to set focus to field. Something like

```
<script>
//call after page loaded
window.onload=setFocus(); 
</script>
```

or

```
<body onload="setFocus();">
```